# padding to get 128 bits in java

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Stack {
    static int count = 0;
    static String res[] = new String[16];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter text");
        String abc = "";
        char[] messChar = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < messChar.length; i++)
            abc += Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]);
        System.out.println(abc.length());
        int leg = (int) ((abc.length() / 128) + 1);
        String[] spl = new String[leg];

        int j = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i < abc.length(); i++) {
            if (count == 128) {
                if (i == 128)
                    spl[j] = abc.substring(0, 128);
                else
                    spl[j] = abc.substring(i - 128, i);
                count = 0;
                j++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        spl[j] = abc.substring(i - count, i);
        for (int k = 0; k < spl.length; k++)
            System.out.println(spl[k].length());
        for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
            String binary = spl[i];
            System.out.println(binary);
        }
    }
}
```

The input for the above code is text. If I give some text, it converts it into binary and then splits it into 128 bits. But at last some bits are remaining which are less than 128 bits. However, I need exactly 128 bits. So how can I do padding to get 128 bits in Java? I am implementing the AES Algorithm 128 bit key.

Comment: Usually you pass the length of the plaintext along with the plaintext, and add zero, or better yet, random bytes as padding. Sometimes the length of the padding is encoded in the padding itself. After deciphering, the padding is detected and discarded. [Read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for real-world examples.

Comment: sir if possible,show example along with the code.

Comment: Sorry, not really possible — I assume it's your homework, and you will not learn without applying your own effort. As a hint: at the end of the splitting loop, you have the last fragment. Check its length, and add as many padding bytes as required to get 128 bit (16 bytes). I wonder why are you working on bit level; AES works on 16-byte  (128 bits) level. Unless your input is not in regular 8-bit bytes, you can use whole bytes as padding. Using padding bytes with values equal to the size of padding (e.g. `05` to pad 5 bytes) looks easiest.